# Check if path to file is correct on Excel Column and Auto Update link

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, hyperlink

I have an Excel file with multiple columns, one of the column has a path to an image in a remote folder (or local, doesn't matter).

```
D:\\folder\1000(12505.2012.05.00000001).jpg
```

I want to check if all the URLs or PATHs to the files are correct

If one is wrong or doesn't point to a real file (or the address is bad) then highlight it in red (or just signal it somehow). and if I repair the image the "checker" is auto update.

```
Function FileExist(path As String) As Boolean
    If Dir(path) <> vbNullString Then FileExist = True
End Function
```

this is the code that I found but it wont auto update if I repair the path or the wrong image (not same as the formula).

Comment: Please include in your question how you use/call `FileExist`

Comment: Excel is a single thread application which means there are limitations. You could potentially have a moodless form that runs in the back ground to periodically checks status of you links or have a column where when you update a broken link, you update that column which inturn triggers the check

Comment: @Peh just put in the module then the module was running in the backround. the formula is =FileExist(AD2229) if it was a correct path then the value in cell is "TRUE" and if not, "FALSE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you update the cell with the path it will automatically update the value of your formula.
2. If you want it to update also if you changed/moved the file then your function needs to be `Volatile` and you need to press F9 to re-calculate them.

   ```
   Function FileExist(ByVal Path As String) As Boolean
       Application.Volatile
       FileExist = Dir(Path) <> vbNullString
   End Function
   ```

Or if you want to keep it non-volatile

```
    Function FileExist(ByVal Path As String) As Boolean
        FileExist = Dir(Path) <> vbNullString
    End Function
```

you need to either re-write the formula or the path data like.

```
Range("A1:A100").Value = Range("A1:A100").Value 're-write path data
'or
Range("B1:B100").Formula = Range("B1:B100").Formula 're-write formula
```

Comment: Thank you for the option number 2! i need that, but still can't be auto update? i must press F9 every i need an update ya?

Comment: Yes, F9 is needed to recalculate all cells. Excel cannot know when to update, so you need to force a  re-calculation of the formula.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Hahaha sorry, my question is “is that function option number 2 that you post just effected 1 cell in which there is fileexist funcion or the workbook”

Comment: Still don't get the point of the question. You can use the function as `=FileExist(A1)` in your cell.

Comment: yes i get that, but this "Application.Volatile" is this affected for 1 cell which is there is Fileexist funcion or all the formula in the workbook.

Comment: Ah now I get it … that is valid for the whole function `FileExist` no matter in which worksheet you use it. It does not affect other functions.

Comment: Thanks! then application.Volatile just affect FileExist Function only not affected other Function or the formula :))